# Using Dividers inside Material-UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

If I want to use a Divider or something else that isn't a Tab inside Material-UI Tabs, I get DOM warnings in the console.

```
<Tabs ...>
  //...
  <Divider />
  //...
</Tabs>
```

A workaround for this is to create a middleman-kind class like this:

```
<Tabs ...>
   //...
   <MDivider />
   //...
</Tabs>

function MDivider(props) {
  return <Divider />;
}
```

But I was thinking if this is the best solution to solve the issue or if there are other, better ways to stop getting the warning.

codesandbox with error [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i1scb)
codesandbox with fix [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7zoyz)

Comment: Related document: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Comment: That still requires you to have a middleman function. Maybe that's the only way.

Comment: @RobertAndrei What is your purpose for putting a divider element there?

Comment: To have a divider between tabs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found the best fix based on how the MUI Tabs are meant to be used. If Tabs are only meant to have MUI Tab children inside, then the MUI-intended way to do this would be to add the Divider like this:

```
<Tab label="" icon={<Divider />} disabled />
```

, give it a className and style it accordingly. The Tab component is a button with stuff inside, so you would need to override some paddings and min-heights in css.

Comment: If someone comes up with a better way to do it, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Dividers in between each Tab as follows:

```
        <Box
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "flex-end",
            marginRight: 20,
          }}
        >
          <Tabs
            sx={{ backgroundColor: "#EAEBEF", borderRadius: 4 }}
            value={tab}
            onChange={(e, v) => setTab(v)}
          >
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Divider
              orientation="vertical"
              style={{ height: 30, alignSelf: "center" }}
            />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
            <Divider
              orientation="vertical"
              style={{ height: 30, alignSelf: "center" }}
            />
            <Tab label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </Box>
```

Comment: this will generate the warning the OP mentions

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to add a border to the top of the tab seems to work well for me.

```js
const useStyles = (theme) => ({
    withDivider: {
        borderTop: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    },
});
```

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab>...<Tab/>
    <Tab>...<Tab/>
    <Tab className={classes.withDivider}>...<Tab/>
    <Tab>...<Tab/>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone wondering why the divider doesn´t show up, add the orientation property and set it to "vertical" so the divider can be visible in horizontal Tabs.

```
<Tab label="" icon={<Divider orientation="vertical" />}  disabled />
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain what the orientation does or how that affects the divider, rather than just saying to add it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please let me know if you come across an even more intuitive property... But sure here is the official documentation for it:
orientation: The component orientation.